# Linq query for complex type model

Tags: c#, linq

I have class with Multiple tables in one model like below:

```
public partial class Nurse
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.Guid> Guid { get; set; }
    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public User user {get;set;}
}
```

I want to fill all data with Nurse class with all details using join like this.

```
public List<Nurse> GetCareNurses(int id)
{
     var result = (from r in _context.Nurses
                          join u in _context.Users on r.UserId equals u.Id
                          where r.sector_id == id
                          select new Nurse { UserId = r.UserId, Name=u.FirstName+" " +u.LastName }).ToList();

    return result.ToList();              
}
```

It should fill data only for 2 fields which I required from both tables but throws error as `The entity or complex type 'WatsonModel.Nurse' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.`.

Comment: What is the problem with your code?

Comment: If this is EF/EF Core you can just get one Nurse and eager load the User-property. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data

Answer (score 0):

You can't project to a mapped entity (Nurse), but you are allowed to project to an anonymous type or a Data Transfer Object (DTO) for passing your data around.

If you create a NurseDTO:

```
public class NurseDTO
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Then call GetCareNurses:

```
//Change 1: Change your List to List of type NurseDTO
 public List<NurseDTO> GetCareNurses(int id)
{
     var result = (from r in _context.Nurses
                          join u in _context.Users on r.UserId equals u.Id
                          where r.sector_id == id
                          //Change 2: Select new NurseDTO
                          select new NurseDTO { UserId = r.UserId, Name=u.FirstName+" " +u.LastName }).ToList();

    return result.ToList();              
}
```

You should return a list of your NurseDTOs